# Xcode: Include of non-modular header inside framework module

Tags: swift, xcode, cordova

I'm getting build errors in Xcode, but the same project compiles fine from xcodebuild. The headers in question (Cordova) are in Carthage/Checkouts, outside the project directory. They do appear under Frameworks, so Xcode is able to find them.

I set "Allow non-modular includes..." to YES, but that didn't change anything, and anyway xcodebuild was building fine without it.

I cleaned out DerivedData... No change.

Anyone seen this? It's so strange that the CLI build works with the same project file.

UPDATE: The header files under Frameworks/CordovaLib/Public all have public Target Membership.